# get list of ids from list of objects from inner list java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have list of entity class:

```
public class Entity
{
    private long id;    
    private List<InnerEnity> data;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<InnerEnity> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

this is InnerEnity class

```
public class InnerEnity 
{
    private long id;    
    private String data;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

what i need is list of InnerEnity ids. 
to resolve this i am trying something like that :-

```
List innerEnityIds = listOfEnity.stream().map(sys -> sys.getData().stream().map(obj->obj.getId().collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Hint: use `flatMap` instead of the first `map`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you need `flatMap`:

```
List<Long> innerEnityIds = 
    listOfEnity.stream() // Stream<Entity>
               .flatMap(sys -> sys.getData().stream().map(InnerEntity::getId)) // Stream<Long>
               .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<Long>
```

Or, you can break the `flatMap` step into `flatMap` + `map`:

```
List<Long> innerEnityIds = 
    listOfEnity.stream() // Stream<Entity>
               .flatMap(sys -> sys.getData().stream()) // Stream<InnerEntity>
               .map(InnerEntity::getId) // Stream<Long>
               .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<Long>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do the trick (haven't tested it):

```
List<Long> innerEntityIds = listOfEnity.stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.getData().stream()) // 1
    .map(ie -> ie.getId())  // 2
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // 3
```

1) stream all the inner entities into one stream using flatMap
2) map each inner entity to its id
3) collect the id's into a list

Comment: getData() is list